# ln() and product confuse me

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic, exponentiation, fractions, products

I have this function:

$p(x_n;\mu) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{l}{2}}|\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\right)$

And I have to compute this: $L(\mu) = \ln\left( \prod\limits_{n=1}^{N} p(x_n;\mu)\right)$ which should be equal to:

$-\frac{N}{2}\, \ln( \space (2\pi)^l|\Sigma|\space) \space- \space \frac{1}{2} \space \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)$

Note: $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix.

---

From my attempt I have:

$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{l}{2}}|\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \ln1 - \ln((2\pi)^{l/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}) = - \ln((2\pi)^{l/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}) = -\frac{L}{2}\ln2\pi - \frac{1}{2}\ln|\Sigma|$

and:

$\ln(\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu))) = -\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)$

but when I put everything together with the product, it doesn't work out, squares appear and it doesn't feel right...Can you help me please *understand*?

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ a number or a matrix?

Comment: @snulty a matrix.

Comment: Is it positive definite for example?

Comment: It is a covariance matrix @snulty, does this help? :)

Comment: Well naively the log of the product is the sum of the logs: $L(\mu)=\sum_{n=1}^N \ln(p(x_n,\mu))$. Then use that $\ln(p(x_n,\mu))=-\frac{1}{2}\ln((2\pi)^l |\Sigma|)-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)$. I say naively because I'm applying ordinary log rules to matrices. Although I guess $p$ is real valued so it's probably fine.

Comment: Yes p is real valued, but I don't get what you are saying. We have p() and we want to write down/expand L(μ) @snulty, sorry!

Comment: Yeah, $L(\mu)=\ln(\prod p)=\sum \ln(p)$

Comment: @snulty what? :O Is that a rule in general?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities Check the section on 'Using simpler operations'.

Comment: Hell yeah! @snulty thank you, I would encourage you to post an answer summarizing your comments please! :) Or do you think that my question is silly and should be deleted? I mean it has 0 score, so probably is not helpful to others...EDIT: I still don't see how $ln(p(xn,μ))=−12ln((2π)l|Σ|)−12(xn−μ)TΣ−1(xn−μ)$ though...

Comment: no it's not silly, I think the question just looks more complicated than the solution. I'll type up an answer in a bit when I'm on my laptop. It just takes a long time on my phone :)

Comment: Hmm let's see @snulty, because I have understood everything, except than the $ln(p(xn,μ))$ equation you wrote on your 3rd comment...Hmmm...I will wait for sure! :)

Comment: Writing an answer now, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that

$$p(x_n;\mu):= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{l}{2}}|\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\right)$$

Since $p$ is real valued we should be able to apply ordinary log rules within reason. These are:

1. $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ which generalises to $\ln\left(\prod_i x_i\right)=\sum_i \ln(x_i)$ for finite sums and products.
2. $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$
3. $\ln(\exp(y))=y$

Now we want to find:

$$L(\mu)=\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^N p(x_n;\mu)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^N\ln(p(x_n;\mu))\quad \text{using point }1. $$

Now we find $\ln(p(x_n;\mu)):$
\begin{align}
\ln(p(x_n;\mu))&= \ln\left((2\pi)^{-l/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\right)\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\left[(2\pi)^l|\Sigma|\right]^{-1/2}\right)+\ln\left(\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\right)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left((2\pi)^l|\Sigma|\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left((2\pi)^l|\Sigma|\right)-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)
\end{align}
We used points $2$ and $3$ in going from line $2$ to $3$ above. Now to do the sum, note the first term doesn't depend on $n$

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\ln(p(x_n;\mu))&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left[-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left((2\pi)^l|\Sigma|\right)-\frac{1}{2}(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\right]\\
&=-\frac{N}{2}\ln\left((2\pi)^l|\Sigma|\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_n-\mu)\\
\end{align}

Which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.Final question: When you compute $ln(p(x_n;μ))$, you had $l/2$ in the exponent of 2π, where did that go?

Comment: @gsamaras So I used that $x^{ab}=(x^a)^b$, so I 'factored' out the common power of minus $\frac12$ from $2\pi$ and $|\Sigma|$. Or altogether that $$(2\pi)^{-l/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}=\left((2\pi)^{l}|\Sigma|\right)^{-1/2}$$